# delete files from git using gitpython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I need to programmatically delete all versions of a particular file from git (including the commit messages from when the files was updated). The versions could be scattered throughout the list of commits.

Example: if there are 10 total commits, and the file in question was updated at commit 3, 4, and 7. I need to delete the file from commit 3 onwards and delete the commit messages at commit 3, 4, and 7.

If the commit history is as follows, `X` marks the commits which I want to delete from commit history along with the file.

```
O - O - X - X - O - O - X - O - O - O
```

1. Is it even possible?
2. If yes, what's the easiest way to do it programmatically? 
   I know that GitPython doesn't have any builtin functionality for this, but it does allow running of git commands on the shell using python.

Comment: I would hope it's not possible, as a full record is kind of the point of Git.

Comment: I agree with @TigerhawkT3 that you're better off keeping the record of most files. Although for some files like binary files or image files ('blobs') which are not easily revision controlled but need to be part of your repo, you can use this tool to clean up your commit history: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Comment: Per [`man git-filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch): "Suppose you want to remove a file (containing confidential information or copyright violation) from all commits:" `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD`. Be sure to use with care.

Comment: @unutbu, I tried `filter-branch`. It deleted the file, which is good, but kept the commit messages for when the file was updated. I want to be able to remove commit messages related to those files as well. Perhaps I should ask it as a separate question...

Comment: @tamjd1: `git filter-branch` also has a `--msg-filter <command>` option. You should be able to use that to clean up the commit messages. There are some examples in the man page.

Comment: Thanks @unutbu. `--msg-filter` option did the trick. Since it seems like there's no way to delete a commit message completely, I can use `--msg-filter` to alter the message to say that the file which was edited at this commit has been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution which worked for me was git command: `"git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch foo.txt' --msg-filter 'sed "s/foo.txt/DELETED/g"'`

This command has two parts:

1. `index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch foo.txt'` - This
   deletes all versions of the file named foo.txt
2. `msg-filter 'sed "s/foo.txt/DELETED/g"'` - This alters the commit messages which contain the filename foo.txt to specify that the file has been deleted

This command removes foo.txt and alters the commit messages which contain foo.txt to specify that the file has been deleted.

Thanks to @unutbu for pointing me to the required filter-branch options.